# How can I change the position of the legend in this R-code?

Tags: r, position, legend

```
library(robfilter)
res <- robust.filter(cow,width=7)
plot(res)
ind <- which(res$ol!=0)
points(ind,cow[ind])
```

I want to have the legend in the top left corner, but when I write a legend command it draws a second legend, but I can't remove the legend that is drawn automatically.

Every help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `robfilter:::plot.robust.filter` function is doing the plotting, and it has `"topright"` hard coded.  You would have to write your own function to override that.  For example:

```
plot.robust.filter <- function (x, legend = "topright", ...) {
    N <- length(x$y)
    ylims <- c(min(x$y, min(x$level, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE), 
        max(x$y, max(x$level, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE))
    xlims <- c(1, N)
    if (x$online) {
        ol.text <- "Online "
    }
    else {
        ol.text <- ""
    }
    if (x$adapt == 0) {
        adapt.text <- paste(" with Window Width ", x$width, sep = "")
    }
    else {
        adapt.text <- " with Adaptive Window Width"
    }
    titel <- paste(ol.text, x$trend, " ", x$outlier, "-", x$scale, 
        " Filter", adapt.text, sep = "")
    plot(x$y, type = "l", main = titel, ylim = ylims, xlim = xlims, 
        xlab = "Time", ylab = x$ts.name)
    lines(x$level, col = "red", lty = 1, lwd = 2)
    legend(x = legend, bty = "n", legend = c("Time Series", 
        "Filtered Signal"), lty = c(1, 1), col = c("black", "red"), 
        lwd = c(1, 2))
}
```

This version defaults to the same location as the original function, but allows you to call it as

```
plot(res, legend = "topleft")
```

to change the location.